# Adding an uploaded file as an <image> element in an SVG

Tags: javascript, image, svg, filereader

If someone uploads an image with a `<input type="file"/>`, there are a million different ways to add the image somewhere as an `<img>` element or onto a `<canvas>`.  I want to instead add it as an `<image>` element in an SVG and I'm totally stymied.

If I add the uploaded file to a canvas and use canvas.getDataURL(), I get a valid data URL that I can use as a background image or whatever.  But setting the `xlink:href` of an `<image>` element to that URL does nothing.  I've also tried adding the file directly without the canvas step, e.g.:

```
$("#file").on("change",function(){
  $("image").attr("xlink:href",this.files[0]);
});
```

That seems to do something but still the image won't display.  I have a width and height set on it.  I've also tried various Blob URL methods and those all don't do anything.

How can I take the image file from a file input and display it as an `<image>` element in an SVG?

Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: probably best to avoid jquery with SVG.xlink:href attributes need to be in the xlink namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The this.files[0] returns a File object. The xlink:href attribute assigment takes string. The automatic conversion of File object to string results in the attribute being assigned the string "[object File]".

You could read the file as a data URL and then assign the data URL to the href attribute. As mentioned in comment by Robert Longson, using JQuery with SVG attribute requiring namespace can sometimes cause problems. I would suggest setting attribute using plain DOM. For example...

```
var xlinkNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

$("#file").on("change",function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $("image")[0].setAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "href", e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0])
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This resolved it.  Also, doing the same sort of modification with d3 instead works fine: `d3.select("image").attr("xlink:href",e.target.result);`